# PHP Background Process on BSD uses 100% CPU

Tags: php, twitter, freebsd, background-process, bsd

I have a PHP script that runs as a background process.  This script simply uses fopen to read from the Twitter Streaming API.  Essentially an http connection that never ends.  I can't post the script unfortunately because it is proprietary.  The script on Ubuntu runs normally and uses very little CPU.  However on BSD the script always uses nearly a 100% CPU.  The script is working just fine on both machines and is the exact same script.  Can anyone think of something that might point me in the right direction to fix this?  This is the first PHP script I have written to consistently run in the background.

The script is an infinite loop, it reads the data out and writes to a json file every minute.  The script will write to a MySQL database whenever a reconnect happens, which is usually after days of running.  The script does nothing else and is not very long.  I have little experience with BSD or writing PHP scripts that run infinite loops.  Thanks in advance for any suggestions, let me know if this belongs in another StackExchange.  I will try to answer any questions as quickly as possible, because I realize the question is very vague.

Comment: Profile with xdebug and kcachegrind?  Trace with gdb?  Can you create a sample script that reproduces the same behavior that you can share with us?

Comment: I've never used xdebug on a development server before, only locally.  I will look into this.  In the mean time I'll try and come up with a short sample script that can reproduce this behavior.

Comment: You make look at something like this to abstract the process management portion of your code: https://github.com/shaneharter/PHP-Daemon

Comment: That looks interesting.  I am actually using Screen as a method for running a background process along with executing shell commands via PHP.  It is really hackish.  Perhaps this has more to do with Screen then the actual script itself.  I will look into this PHP-Daemon it sounds a lot better than screen.

Comment: DaveRandom's answer lead me to figuring out that screen for some odd reason is the perpetrator not the actual script.  The script runs fine from command line.  However running the script behind screen goes out of control.  Screen does not go out of control on Ubuntu, only on BSD.  I am going to look into PHP-Daemon and other solutions for this.  Thanks for the help and specifically thanks for the PHP-Daemon solution Aknosis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the script, this is very difficult to give you a definitive answer, however what you need to do is ensure that your script is waiting for data appropriately. What you should absolutely definitely *not* do is call `stream_set_timeout($fp, 0);` or `stream_set_blocking($fp, 0);` on your file pointer.

The basic structure of a script to do something like this that should avoid racing would be something like this:

```
// Open the file pointer and set blocking mode
$fp = fopen('http://www.domain.tld/somepage.file','r');
stream_set_timeout($fp, 1);
stream_set_blocking($fp, 1);

while (!feof($fp)) { // This should loop until the server closes the connection

  // This line should be pretty much the first line in the loop
  // It will try and fetch a line from $fp, and block for 1 second
  // or until one is available. This should help avoid racing
  // You can also use fread() in the same way if necessary
  if (($str = fgets($fp)) === FALSE) continue;

  // rest of app logic goes here

}
```

You can use `sleep()`/`usleep()` to avoid racing as well, but the better approach is to rely on a blocking function call to do your blocking. If it works on one OS but not on another, try setting the blocking modes/behaviour explicitly, as above.

If you can't get this to work with a call to `fopen()` passing a HTTP URL, it may be a problem with the HTTP wrapper implementation in PHP. To work around this, you could use `fsockopen()` and handle the request yourself. This is not too difficult, especially if you only need to send a single request and read a constant stream response.

Comment: I just tried your code.  The code works fine, but I'm still running at 100%.  I remember having some trouble of some kind with fsockopen(), but I will look into it.

Comment: If the process is running at 100%, it suggests the call to `fgets()` is not blocking. If you add the line `echo time();` immediately before that line, I would expect to see a UNIX timestamp output once a second (when there is no data to receive from the socket) - can you test this and see if it is the case?

Comment: You are correct, this works fine when I run from php command.  However the problem is not the php command, it seems to be screen.  I have been using screen to run the process as a sort of daemon.  It's very hackish I know, but your answer lead to me figuring this out.  Thanks for the help and showing me how this should be done.  I am going to try out PHP-Daemon as another user suggested.  The code you provided works perfectly on BSD unless it is run behind screen.  For some reason screen goes out of control with this particular script on BSD but not on Ubuntu.

Comment: If I need to run a PHP script as a daemon, I tend to put a `::respawn:php /path/to/my/script` line in inittab. Of course, you can't do this on BSD, since it has no inittab, but there must be an equivalent you could use - I know peanuts about BSD so I can't say exactly what that might be, but there must be something... Maybe [this](http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/bsd-guru/when-inittab-doesnt-exist-16179) might help?

Comment: I will check into this.  Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like one of your functions is blocking briefly on Linux, but not BSD.  Without seeing your script it is hard to get specific, but one thing I would suggest is to add a [`usleep()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usleep.php) before the next loop iteration:

```
usleep(100000); //Sleep for 100ms
```

You don't need a long sleep... just enough so that you're not using 100% CPU.

**Edit:** Since you mentioned you don't have a good way to run this in the background right now, I suggest checking out [this tutorial for "daemonizing" your script](http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/create_daemons_in_php/).  Included is some handy code for doing this.  It can even make a file in `init.d` for you.

Comment: I should have mentioned I have tried with and without usleep to no effect.  I think I need to find a good article explaining blocking.  Finding information specific to running PHP as a background process is very hard to find.  I need to find something to educate myself about this subject.

Comment: @Caimen, running has a background or foreground process makes no difference.  If you run PHP standalone, this is nearly identical to running it CGI.  The only time you run into bigger differences is if you run PHP with FastCGI or ISAPI, where PHP is hosted by another process.  Otherwise, a process is a process is a process.

Answer (score 0):

How does the code look like that does the actual reading? Do you just hammer the socket until you get something?

One really effective way to deal with this is to use the [libevent extension](http://pecl.php.net/package/libevent), but that's not for the feeble minded.